# Add additional array to serialized form data

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I would like to make an ajax jquery post. I have serialized the form data but my endpoint requires additional values to be added to the serialized form data to be posted together.

The object to be appended to the serialized form data is

```
"bridgeConfigurations": [
    {
        "configName":"Provider_Account_Id",
        "configValue":"xxxxx"
    },
    {
    "configName":"Provider_Auth_Token",
    "configValue":"xxxxx"
    }
]
```

Any help on how this can be achieved

Comment: Do you mean serialized?

Comment: Var data = $(form).serializeArray();

Comment: Can you show in what format they expect it? JSON.stringify or $.param() ?

Comment: var data = JSON.stringify($(form).serializeArray())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine like this, i am not sure what is your exact expectation. i have added 3 examples:

```js
var $form = $('form');
var data = {
  "bridgeConfigurations": [
    {
      "configName":"Provider_Account_Id",
      "configValue":"xxxxx"
    },
    {
      "configName":"Provider_Auth_Token",
      "configValue":"xxxxx"
    }
  ]
};

// EXAMPLE 1
let formData = $($form).serializeArray();
let mergeData = $.merge(formData, data["bridgeConfigurations"]);
let finalData = JSON.stringify(mergeData);
console.log("Example 1: ", finalData);

// EXAMPLE 2
let formData1 = $($form).serializeArray();
let mergeData1 = $.merge(formData1, [data]);
let finalData1 = JSON.stringify(mergeData1);
console.log("Example 2: ", finalData1);

// EXAMPLE 3
let formData2 = $($form).serializeArray();
let formDatas2 = {};
formData2.forEach((value) => { formDatas2[value['name']] = value['value']; });
let mergeData2 = $.extend({}, formDatas2, data);
let finalData2 = JSON.stringify(mergeData2);
console.log("Example 3: ", finalData2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="demoName">
  <input type="email" name="email" value="dummy@mail.com">
</form>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

A useful API I'd recommend is the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```js
// Your object
const cfg = {
  "bridgeConfigurations": [{
      "configName": "Provider_Account_Id",
      "configValue": "xxxxx"
    },
    {
      "configName": "Provider_Auth_Token",
      "configValue": "xxxxx"
    }
  ]
};

$("#cfgForm").on("submit", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser follow form-Action

  // Init FormData for form and its current fields values
  const FD = new FormData(this); // `this` is the cfgForm

  // Add bridgeConfigurations stuff to formData
  cfg.bridgeConfigurations.forEach(item => {
    FD.append("configName[]", item.configName);
    FD.append("configValue[]", item.configValue);
  });

  // Send the FormData
  $.ajax({
    url: "example.php",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false, // https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
    data: FD, // pass the formData 
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });

});
```